# Extract information out of strings

Tags: python, string

given in a string the following information:

> [:T102684-1 coord="107,20,885,18":]27.[:/T102684-1:] [:T102684-2
>   coord="140,16,885,18":]A.[:/T102684-2:] [:T102684-3
>   coord="162,57,885,18":]Francke[:/T102684-3:][:T102684-4
>   coord="228,5,885,18":]:[:/T102684-4:] [:T102684-5
>   coord="240,27,885,18":]Die[:/T102684-5:] [:T102684-6
>   coord="274,42,885,18":]alpine[:/T102684-6:] [:T102684-7
>   coord="325,64,885,18":]Literatur[:/T102684-7:] [:T102684-8
>   coord="398,25,885,18":]des[:/T102684-8:] [:T102684-9
>   coord="427,46,885,18":]Jahres[:/T102684-9:] [:T102684-10
>   coord="480,33,885,18":]1888[:/T102684-10:] [:T102684-11
>   coord="527,29,885,18":]475[:/T102684-11:]

How can I extract the Tab-ID (here: T102684), the Token-ID (the number after the "-"), the coordinates (107,20,885,18) and the token itself ("27.") ? 
I used simple find-methods, but it doesn't work...

```
for tok in ele.text.split():
        print tok.find("[:T")
        print tok.rfind(":]")
        print tok[(tok.find("[:T")+2):tok.rfind("-")]
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: And why does it not work. What problem do you get with the code you have shown?

Comment: Could you please include some more sample lines?

Comment: Done. :) 
It doesn't work, because I don't get the correct beginning and end of the desired information.

Comment: This is one paragraph. I do the following: span_element = data.find_all('span')
    for ele in span_element:
        print ele.text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex for this:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '[:T102684-1 coord="107,20,885,18":]27.[:/T102684-1:] [:T102684-2 coord="140,16,885,18":]A.[:/T102684-2:] [:T102684-3 coord="162,57,885,18":]Francke[:/T102684-3:][:T102684-4 coord="228,5,885,18":]:[:/T102684-4:] [:T102684-5 coord="240,27,885,18":]Die[:/T102684-5:] [:T102684-6 coord="274,42,885,18":]alpine[:/T102684-6:] [:T102684-7 coord="325,64,885,18":]Literatur[:/T102684-7:] [:T102684-8 coord="398,25,885,18":]des[:/T102684-8:] [:T102684-9 coord="427,46,885,18":]Jahres[:/T102684-9:] [:T102684-10 coord="480,33,885,18":]1888[:/T102684-10:] [:T102684-11 coord="527,29,885,18":]475[:/T102684-11:]'
>>> r = re.compile(r'''\[:/?T(?P<token_id>\d+)-(?P<id>\d+)\s+coord="
                    (?P<coord>(\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+))":\](?P<token>\w+)''', flags=re.VERBOSE)
>>> for m in r.finditer(s):
        print m.groupdict()


{'token_id': '102684', 'token': '27', 'id': '1', 'coord': '107,20,885,18'}
{'token_id': '102684', 'token': 'A', 'id': '2', 'coord': '140,16,885,18'}
{'token_id': '102684', 'token': 'Francke', 'id': '3', 'coord': '162,57,885,18'}
{'token_id': '102684', 'token': 'Die', 'id': '5', 'coord': '240,27,885,18'}
{'token_id': '102684', 'token': 'alpine', 'id': '6', 'coord': '274,42,885,18'}
{'token_id': '102684', 'token': 'Literatur', 'id': '7', 'coord': '325,64,885,18'}
{'token_id': '102684', 'token': 'des', 'id': '8', 'coord': '398,25,885,18'}
{'token_id': '102684', 'token': 'Jahres', 'id': '9', 'coord': '427,46,885,18'}
{'token_id': '102684', 'token': '1888', 'id': '10', 'coord': '480,33,885,18'}
{'token_id': '102684', 'token': '475', 'id': '11', 'coord': '527,29,885,18'}
```